# Highest Weights of Defining and Adjoint Representations of $\mathfrak{so}_5$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

I am asked to describe the defining representation of $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ in terms of highest weights, and then I am asked to repeat this process for the defining and adjoint representations of $\mathfrak{so}_5$

To start with, I noted that the subalgebra of diagonal matrices in $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ gave a Cartan Subalgebra $\mathfrak{t}$ that is spanned by the two diagonal $4\times 4$ matrices, $t_1 = diag(1,0,1,0)$ and $t_2 = diag(0,1,0,1)$.

Knowing this, suppose we take any vector $v = (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb R^4$, then:

$t_1v = (a,0,c,0)$ and $t_2v = (0,b,0,d)$.

Hence, if $v$ were in the $\omega$ weight space of $V = \mathbb R^4$, then:

Either $\omega(t_1) = 0$ or $ b = d = 0$, and:

Either $\omega(t_2) = 0$ or $a = c = 0$.

Putting these two things together I concluded that $V = V_0$ is the $0$-weight space, and hence $V$ has highest weight $0$.

Second, noting that $\mathfrak{so}_5 \cong \mathfrak{sp}_4$, I argued that the defining representation of $\mathfrak{so}_5$ would behave in the same way, and thus would all be the $0$-weight space.

However, I feel like I must have made a mistake here somewhere because this doesn't seem right to me.

Additionally, I am unsure how to proceed to answer the part about the adjoint representation.

I think I will be taking the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{t}$ of diagonal matrices in $\mathfrak{so}_5$, with some basis $t_1, t_2$.

Then I suppose I would take a general matrix $x \in \mathfrak{so}_5$ and compute $t_1x -  xt_1 $ and $t_2x - xt_2$ to see if these are non-trivial scalar multiples of $x$. If so then $x$ can belong to some non-zero weight space of $V = \mathbb R^5$.

I wanted to ask though if there would be a better way to do questions of this kind.

Comment: Do you know about Dynkin diagrams? Under your isomorphism the standard representation of $\mathfrak{so}_5$ corresponds to the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagonal matrices you set up are not completely correct (since any matrix in $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ is tracefree). It should be $t_1=diag(1,0,-1,0)$ and $t_2=diag(0,1,0,-1)$. Now since weights are linear functionals, they are best expressed in terms of the dual basis to $\{t_1,t_2\}$ which usually is denoted by $\{e_1,e_2\}$. So $e_1$ extracts the first entry of a diagonal matrix and $e_2$ extracts the second of these entries. Now consider the standard basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_4\}$ of $\mathbb C^4$. By defintion $t_1v_1=v_1=e_1(t_1)v_1$ and $t_2v_1=0=e_2(t_1)v_1$, so $v_1$ is a weight vector of weight $e_1$. Similarly, the other $v_i$ are weight vectors with weights $e_2$, $-e_1$ and $-e_2$, respectively. The standard ordering of weights is that $e_1>e_2>0$, so the highest weight is $e_1$. For the adjoint representation you have to work similarly using an appropriate basis of $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ consisting of matrices with only one or two non-zero entries. Just give it a try. For $\mathfrak{so}_5$ you first need a Cartan subalgebra, then you can analyze the representations similarly, showing the as stated in the comment of @David_Hill that the standard representation of $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ corresponds to the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{so}_5$ and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I am a little lost however on two parts. What do you mean by "$e_1$ extracts the first entry of a diagonal matrix"? Do you mean that because it only returns $1$ for the $t_1$ component, and because the first entry of a diagonal matrix is the first entry of the $t_1$ component, then we are effectively taking this value? Secondly, what exactly are $s_1, s_2$? In the line that you introduce $s_2$ I would have expected you to use $e_2$ as $e_2(t_1) = 0$. Is $s_2$ a scalar multiple of $s_2$ here? In which case why couldn't we have just used $e_2$?

Comment: I am sorry, I have changed notation during writing the reply and didn't do this completely. I have now edited the answer, hopefully correcting this. (I have removed $s_1$ and $s_2$ now.) What I mean by $e_1$ is the functional that sends $diag(a,b,-a,-b)$ to $a$, while $e_2$ sends it to $b$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I understand now!